# Image convolution in MATLAB - how is conv is 360x faster than my hand-coded version?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, vector, convolution

I am playing with image processing algorithms in MATLAB. One of the basic ones is convolving an image with a Gaussian. I ran the following test on a grayscale 800x600 image:

```
function [Y1, Y2] = testConvolveTime(inputImage)
[m,n] = size(inputImage);

% casting...
inputImage = cast(inputImage, 'single');

Gvec = [1 4 6 4 1]; % sigma=1;

Y1 = zeros(size(inputImage)); % modify it
Y2 = zeros(size(inputImage)); % modify it


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MATLAB CONV %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
t1 = cputime;

for i=1:m
    Y1(i,:) = conv(inputImage(i,:),Gvec,'same');
end

for j=1:n
    Y1(:,j) = conv(inputImage(:,j),Gvec','same');
end
      
Y1 = round(Y1 / 16);
e1 = cputime - t1

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HAND-CODED CONV %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
t2 = cputime;

for i=1:m
    Y2(i,:) = myConv(inputImage(i,:),Gvec)';
end

for j=1:n
    Y2(:,j) = myConv(inputImage(:,j),Gvec');
end
      
Y2 = round(Y2 / 16);
e2 = cputime - t2

end
```

Here is the code I wrote implementing convolution of 2 vectors:

```
% mimic MATLAB's conv(u,v,'same') function
% always returns column vec
function y = myConv(u_in, v_in)

len1 = length(u_in);
len2 = length(v_in);

if (len1 >= len2)
   u = u_in;
   v = v_in;
else
   u = v_in;
   v = u_in;
end

% from here on: v is the shorter vector (len1 >= len2)

len1 = length(u); 
len2 = length(v); 
maxLen = len1 + len2 - 1;

ytemp = zeros(maxLen,1);

% first part -- partial overlap
for i=1:len2-1
    sum = 0;
    for j=1:i
       sum = sum + u(i-j+1)*v(j);
    end
    ytemp(i) = sum;
end

% main part -- complete overlap
for i=len2:len1
    sum = 0;
    for j=1:len2
       sum = sum + u(i-j+1)*v(j);
    end
    ytemp(i) = sum;
end

% finally -- end portion
for i=len1+1:maxLen
    %i-len1+1
    sum = 0;
    for j=i-len1+1:len2
       sum = sum + u(i-j+1)*v(j);
    end
    ytemp(i) = sum;
end

%y = ytemp;

startIndex = round((maxLen - length(u_in))/2 + 1);
y = ytemp(startIndex:startIndex+length(u_in)-1); 
% ^ note: to match MATLAB's conv(u,v,'same'), the output length must be
%   that of the first argument. 
end
```

Here are my test results:

```
>> [Y1, Y2] = testConvolveTime(A1);

e1 =

    0.5313


e2 =

  195.8906

>> norm(Y1 - Y2)

ans =

     0
```

The norm being 0 verifies mathematical correctness. My questions are as follows:

1. How can my hand-coded function be >360x slower than the one that uses MATLAB's conv?
2. Even MATLAB's conv is still "slow" for image processing. If convolving with a Gaussian takes 0.5 of a second, what hope is there for running any image processing algorithms in real-time (e.g. at 24 FPS)? For reference my CPU is Intel N3540 @ 2.16 GHz. w/ 8GB of RAM.
3. ^ The real question: when I switch to OpenCV on C++, will operations like this become much faster?

Comment: Hi JDS, I can't vouch for OpenCV or real time image processing, but a lot of Matlab functions are open to read. If you type : `edit conv`, you might be able to review their code and see how they are performing their convolution.

Comment: On my MATLAB (R2012b) `conv` just calls `conv2` which does not have source available.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Figured it was worth a try.

Comment: @JDS the killer with your code is that you use `for` loops.  In most cases, MATLAB is notoriously slow when using loops as MATLAB is an interpreted language and there is no optimization (some of the time).  Recent versions of MATLAB use the Just-In-Time (JIT) optimization and so once they see a pattern with using a loop, optimizations will be made on the fly.  However, I can't see JIT working in your case with your code.  In any case, echoing with Dima said to you below, `conv` and `imfilter` are built-in MATLAB functions that are highly optimized for real-time performance.

Comment: With regards to your last question, you probably will not see much of a difference when switching to OpenCV C++.  Remember, `conv` is a built-in function that most likely uses some variation of LAPACK / Suitesparse, which is highly optimized C and FORTRAN code that performs numerical computation and analysis.  OpenCV is built upon similar optimizations and so if you ran the equivalent function calls between OpenCV and MATLAB side-by-side, you will probably get comparable performance.

Answer (score 5):

1) `conv` is so much faster because it is an built-in native function, while your function is interpreted MATLAB code with nested loops.

2) Try `imfilter` in the Image Processing Toolbox. It may be faster than `conv`, and it works on `uint8` arrays. Or, if you get a more recent version of MATLAB, and if you only need the Gaussian filter, try `imgaussfilt`.

Comment: If I can add one more thing, the image processing toolbox takes advantage of Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IIPP).  If your CPU can handle this framework (most can as a good majority of CPUs out there are Intel), this is the main reason why many of the functions in the image processing toolbox are fast.

Comment: It's much faster especially because it goes through FFT which requires less complexity.

Comment: @JemCpp IIRC, `imfilter` and `conv` does not perform filtering using the FFT. Do you have documentation or can you refer me to some reference that supports your statement?

Comment: I got very close to MATLAB in my C Implementation - https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/ImageConvolution. Do you have ideas to get it even faster?

Answer (score 2):

Because (discrete) convolution is often represented via linear algebra but certainly not via for loops. In fact everytime you walk through rows or columns you should seek for ways to represent it as an algebraic operation.

The typical way is to do it via Toeplitz matrices but can be extended to way faster algorithms. And once you have the toeplitz structure then you can optimize the multiplication even further

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix#Discrete_convolution

http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node384.html

Note that native Matlab functions can still be slow. It is not an indication of speed but maintenance level. Often you can find the algorithm used linked in the documentation and you can decide whether you should go for the custom implementation or the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Why convolution in matalab is faster?
The implementation itself is very efficient. 
They use fast techniques to perform multiplication and convolution.
check the BLAS, ATLAS packages if you want to see tricks to do these things very fast.

in practical (convolution in the original domain \ time or space) and   (multiplication in frequency domain) are equivalent. what they do is to transform to frequency domain by using FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) and then perform the multiplication and then go back to the original domain.